# The lists become empty when referenced from another class, where am i doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, object, generics, scope, generic-collections

I have a class movie, where I have auto-implemented List 'Shows' to add Show class objects. I am able to add and access it in the `main` method, but when I call the list from another class named `Access`, it gives me an empty list.

I instantiated `Movie` class in `Access` class but it is creating new list instead of getting the already existing list.

I need to have a non-parameterized constructor in `Movie` class. I also need to be able to access the same `List` 'Shows' in other classes also.

```
// The Movie class where i create the list and store all show class objects

public class Movie
{
        public List<Show> Shows { get; set; }

        public Movie()
        {
            this.Shows = new List<Show>();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // create new object of Show type
            Show s = new Show(153, 258, 391);

            Movie mv = new Movie();

            // add object to List
            mv.Shows.Add(s);

            // The output gives me 153, which is correct
            Console.WriteLine(mv.Shows.ElementAt(0).ShowID);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Show
    {
        public int ShowID { get; set; }
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public int TheatreID { get; set; }

        public Show(int showid, int movieid, int theatreid)
        {
                this.ShowID = showid;
                this.MovieID = movieid;
                this.TheatreID = theatreid;
        }
    }
```

```
   // i need to Access the list in this class
   public class Access
   {
       Movie mov = new Moive();

       // the output is showing null value error
       Console.WriteLine(mov.Shows.ElementAt(0).ShowID);
   }
```

I need to get be able to get and set the List from other classes in the same namespace

Comment: You access a new Movie class instance, which of course is empty. Also: Your code has typos; nort helpful if one wold try to run it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems logical since you instantiate your show list (**Shows**) in the constructor, each time you instantiate **Movie** a new show list (**Shows**) will be instantiated.

> In your case you must use singleton pattern

**The singleton pattern** is a Creational design pattern, which guarantees a single instance of an object.

```
private static List<Show> shows;

public static List<Show> Shows
{
    get
    {
        if (shows == null)
        {
            shows = new List<Show>();
        }
        return shows;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I now understand why list always becomes empty when i instantiate the class. Thank you, learnt something new. :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read your code carefully. In `Main` method you create new `Movie` object (lets call it `movieA`), and you add new `Show` object to `movieA`. In `Access` class you are not using `MovieA`, but once again you create a new `Movie` object. If you want to access `Movie` created in `Main` method, in `Access` class, you have to pass it there.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // create new object of Show type
    Show s = new Show(153, 258, 391);

    Movie movieA = new Movie();

    // add object to List
    movieA.Shows.Add(s);

    // The output gives me 153, which is correct
    Console.WriteLine(movieA.Shows.ElementAt(0).ShowID);

    var access = new Access();
    access.MyMethod(movieA);
}

public class Access
{
   public void MyMethod(Movie movie)
   {
       // this should work
       Console.WriteLine(movie.Shows.ElementAt(0).ShowID);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have made my properties static which helped me to gain access to the same list everywhere in the class and in other classes

Answer (score 0):

You should have a parameterized constructor for you Access class which accepts the Movie object.

Answer (score 0):

In `Access` you create a new `Movie`, instead you need to take the `Movie` already created.

```
public class Access
{
    public void ShowMovieOutput(Movie mov)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mov.Shows.ElementAt(0).ShowID);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // create new object of Show type
    Show s = new Show(153, 258, 391);

    Movie mv = new Movie();

    // add object to List
    mv.Shows.Add(s);

    Access.ShowMovieOutput(mv);

    // The output gives me 153, which is correct
    Console.WriteLine(mv.Shows.ElementAt(0).ShowID);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I worked around with the code but it still didn't help me, I am not using static methods so i have to instantiate the code in access class again which makes the list empty again. But your answer helped in another part that's been giving me some trouble. Thank you :)